# What objects are present in memory in this JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Given the following code, what user-defined objects are in memory after line 1 and after line 2?

```
function MyCtor() {}

//At this point a single user-defined object exists, the constructor function `MyCtor`

var v = new MyCtor();

//Here in addition to the constructor function defined above we have `v` (a `MyCtor` instance) and another instance of `MyCtor` acting as `v.__proto__`. So that is 3 objects in total.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the first line there are two objects. There is the function object, and there is the prototype object for the function.

(Well, the function is created already when the code is parsed, so the objects exist before the code even starts to execute. More correct would be to say that the first line causes two objects to exist.)

After the second line there is just one more object, the instance of the object. The `__proto__` property of the object does not contain another instance of the object, it's a reference to the prototype object of the constructor function.

Example:

```
function MyCtor() {}

console.log(MyCtor.prototype);

var v = new MyCtor();

console.log(v.__proto__);
console.log(MyCtor.prototype === v.__proto__);
```

Output:

```
MyCtor { }
MyCtor { }
true
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/323bg/

Comment: So after line 1, an instance of MyCtor has been created without running the function itself. Can I achieve this behavior directly in any other way?

Comment: The double underscore shows is not a standard property and there are no guarantees it will exist in all browsers.

Comment: @Ben: No, there is no instance of `MyCtor` until the second line creates one. The prototype object for the function is not an instance of `MyCtor`.

Comment: @Guffa But `function Foo() {}; Foo.prototype` returns `Foo {}`, indicating that an instance of `Foo` is acting as the prototype of the constructor function, no?

Comment: @Ben: It looks like an instance when you display it, but it's not. First of all, the constructor function would need to be called to create a proper instance, and it isn't. Second, if it was an instance of the object, then its `__proto__` reference would be itself, but it's the prototype for `Object`: http://jsfiddle.net/323bg/1/